# Facebook React.js :: how to create form input field and set type, autofocus, required etc

Tags: reactjs

Using REACTjs I can create form input fields as follows:

```
React.render(
  React.createElement('input', null, 'Hello, text input'),
  document.getElementById('example')
);

React.render(
  React.createElement('textarea', null, 'Hello, textarea'),
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

My desired input fields need to resemble this:

```
 <input autofocus type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" required>
```

or

```
 <input type="url" name="website" pattern="(http|https)://.+" required>
```

How do I set `autofocus`, `type`, `palceholder` & `required` using `React.createElement();`?

Do I use the `props` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [`createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) uses the second `props` argument for [(supported) attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#html-attributes).

So you can write:

```
React.createElement('input', { placeholder: 'Enter a url', type: 'url', autoFocus: true }, 'default_url');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of code I've used

JSX

```
<button type="submit" className="postfix" disabled={this.isDisabled()}>Automate</button>
```

No JSX

```
React.createElement('button', {
    type: 'submit',
    className: 'postfix',
    disabled: this.isDisabled()
}, 'Automate')
```

You simply use the properties object which is the second argument to React.createElement();

More info on supported attributes: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html